# How to loop over array values using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display array value using `ng-repeat`, and i will call getimage function with itemid and photoidlist to get image url.

My json is:

```
$scope.productslist = {
  "json": {
    "response": {
      "servicetype": "10",
      "functiontype": "104",
      "statuscode": "0",
      "statusmessage": "Success",
      "data": [
        {
          "itemid": 247,
          "isproduct": true,
          "disable": false,
          "itemcost": 150,
          "itemdescription": "prdct",
          "itemname": "pro1",
          "itemno": "#1Pro",
          "itemcategoryid": 158,
          "itemcategory": "General",
          "addedby": "buzi by pree"
        },
        {
          "itemid": 257,
          "isproduct": true,
          "disable": false,
          "itemcost": 150,
          "itemdescription": "products",
          "itemname": "pro 2",
          "itemno": "pro 2",
          "itemcategoryid": 158,
          "itemcategory": "General",
          "photoidlist": [
            138
          ],
          "addedby": "buzi by pree"
        },
        {
          "itemid": 259,
          "isproduct": true,
          "disable": false,
          "itemcost": 150,
          "itemdescription": "descc",
          "itemname": "pro 1",
          "itemno": "pro 3",
          "itemcategoryid": 158,
          "itemcategory": "General",
          "photoidlist": [
            139, 140
          ],
          "addedby": "buzi by pree"
        },
        {
          "itemid": 262,
          "isproduct": true,
          "disable": false,
          "itemcost": 599,
          "itemdescription": "fgg",
          "itemname": "ff",
          "itemno": "r",
          "itemcategoryid": 158,
          "itemcategory": "General",
          "addedby": "buzi by pree"
        },
        {
          "itemid": 263,
          "isproduct": true,
          "disable": false,
          "itemcost": 56,
          "itemdescription": "ffr",
          "itemname": "rf",
          "itemno": "fe",
          "itemcategoryid": 158,
          "itemcategory": "General",
          "photoidlist": [
            140, 143, 141
          ],
          "addedby": "buzi by pree"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Now I need to iterate over the array using `ng-repeat` and display all the values with its particular value.

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/30337/)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is good, but you are trying to iterate over an object, instead of an array. I think it should be the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in productslist.json.response.data">
     ...
</tr>
```

[**Forked your Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xL2poL7t/)